How many non intersecting line segments are there?
Given two parallel lines, $20$ points are selected from each line. In how many ways can $20$ line segments be drawn with endpoints in the given points such that no two lines intersect each other (multiple lines may meet at the same endpoint though)?
My attempt is as follows:
Let’s call the two parallel lines top and bottom. Let the points on the bottom line be $a_1,\dots,a_{20}$ and those on the top line be $b_1,\dots,b_{20}$. If we take point $a_1$ we can connect it to any point $b_{i_1}$ where $1\le i_1\le 20$. Then take the second point $a_2$, it can be connected to any point $b_{i_2}$ where $i_1\le i_2\le 20$. And so on we can construct an increasing sequence $1\le i_1\le i_2\le\cdots\le i_{20}\le 20$. This is where I get stuck and don’t know how to proceed. I feel like I’m really close to finishing the proof from here but I’m missing something. Please help me finish the proof.

Isn't the answer $1$?  If you take the $x-$axis and the line $y=1$ as your lines, and order your points $a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_n$, and $b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_n$ then we have to connect $a_1$ to $b_1$ and so on, else you will run out of points to connect to.

Answer seems to be related to the number of noncrossing partitions on $2n$ elements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition If a line connects point $a_i$ with $b_j$, then $b_i$ through $b_j$ (provided they're not already used) along with $a_i$ are included in the part to avoid crossings

Can we connect $a_i$ to the same $b_j$ multiple times?

@AdamDougall i’d assume so since otherwise the answer is trivial as you said (if we can only do 20 lines exactly)

I mean like $a_3$ to $b_7$ and another line also from $a_3$ to $b_7$. I assume this isn't allowed

If, say, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are both connected to, say, $b_7$, doesn't that mean that the lines intersect at the point $b_7$?

@GerryMyerson by intersecting it’s meant that they intersect in the space between the top and bottom parallel lines

That condition ought to appear in the body of the question, not just here in the comments.

I've used $n = 3$ instead of $20$ to illustrate the argument.
First we biject from the non-intersecting graphs to a table of dimension $2 \times (n+1)$. For example, consider this graph:

Start at the top of graph and write down how many points away from the top the first line segment is. In this example $(0,1)$. And then move down the graph writing down the gap to the next line segment: $(1,1), (1,0)$. And then we add an extra term which counts the gap between the last line and the bottom: $(0,0)$. Note you could also start at the bottom and work up to generate the same table:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline 0 & 1 \\
  \hline 1 & 1 \\
  \hline 1 & 0 \\
  \hline 0 & 0 \\
  \hline 
\end{array}
Now we want to count how many ways there are to fill this table. There are certain rules that we must obey:

We are only allowed rows of $(0,0)$ on the first and last row. Otherwise we would have repeat edges.
Both columns must sum to $(n-1)$.

We'll start by choosing where to place $0$'s in the left column. And then divide the $(n-1)$ between the remaining boxes using stars and bars.
Ignoring the top and bottom rows, let's say there are $0 \le k \le (n-1)$ zeros in the left column. Then there are $\binom{n-1}{k}$ ways of placing the $0$'s. Now we have $(n+1-k)$ boxes left in which to divide up $(n-1)$. However, to avoid double counting, we cannot have any more $0$'s in the middle rows.
Let's assign each of the non-zero middle rows a value of $1$ (there are $[(n-1) - k]$ such rows) and now we divide up the remaining $(n-1)-[(n-1) - k] = k$ between the $(n+1-k)$ non-zero rows (the top and bottom could still be $0$ though).
Using stars and bars, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to do this.
Now we fill in the right column. The $k$ middle rows which contain a $0$ in the left column must have at least $1$ in the right column (we don't worry about the top or bottom rows since $(0,0)$ is allowed here). So just as before, we will initially give these rows a value of $1$ and now we have $(n-1-k)$ left to divide up across the $(n+1)$ rows.
Using stars and bars, there are $\binom{2n-k+1}{n+1}$ ways to do this.
Combining everything, we get that the total numbers of graphs is given by:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n-k-1}{n}$$
Through a change of variables $r = n-k$, we can rewrite this as:
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{r} \binom{n}{r+1} \binom{n+r}{r}$$
Evaluating at $n=20$, we get $3{,}294{,}144{,}659{,}048{,}391{,}059$.
There is more information about this sequence at OEIS where they also give the following equivalent expressions:
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k} \binom{n+k-1}{k}$
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$

Apparently if you square the values in Pascal's triangle, then perform a Hilbert Transform, the column $1$ to the right of centre produces the values to this problem. These also correspond to the $(n+2)^{th}$ term in the Crystal Ball sequence for an $A_n$ lattice.
https://oeis.org/A108625
https://oeis.org/A108625/table
